# use TransferFrom in solidity smartcontract ( ERC-20 )

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I Need to Write a Smart Contract, In This Smart Contract User Can Send Token to Each Account in ERC-20 Network.

`sender` :`0x5C2879Ec550e2F65D557b540B7DEAB3A6d478d62`

`recipient` : `0xB643992c9fBcb1Cb06b6C9eb278b2ac35e6a2711`

`token Address` : `0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088`

**Kovan Testnet**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract DexB is ERC20("KiaDex","DEX") {

   function SendTokenFromAddress(address token,address sender,address recipient,uint256 amount)
    external {

        IERC20 token = IERC20(token);
        token.allowance(sender,address(token));
        token.approve(sender,amount);
        require(token.balanceOf(sender) >=amount , "your balance is low" ) ;
        token.transferFrom(sender,recipient, amount);
        
    }
}
```

when i want to send token from this address `0x5C2879Ec550e2F65D557b540B7DEAB3A6d478d62` to this address `0xB643992c9fBcb1Cb06b6C9eb278b2ac35e6a2711` it dose not work and show me this message and afte that show not success transaction :

[image]

**whats the problem ? how can i sene Token from User Address to User Address in solidity ? **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sender, which in your case is `0x5C2879Ec550e2F65D557b540B7DEAB3A6d478d62` needs to approve the wallet address that's calling the `sendTokenFromAddress` function. The contract cannot do that on behalf of the account that needs to send tokens.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).